There are shootings happening in those communities every day

"My concern is even with the numbers down, there are still too many deaths," he told CBS 3's Walt Hunter. "They don't feel any more safe in their neighborhoods than they did two, three, four, five years ago. There are shootings happening in those communities every day."

Source: https://www.cbsnews.com/amp/philadelphia/news/mayor-nutter-praises-police-local-groups-for-drop-in-violent-crime-in-philadelphia/

I'm having trouble understanding the grammar of the bold part.
"There are shootings happening in those communities every day" has the same meaning as "There are shootings that are happening in those communities every day", but it would seem to me that "happening in those communities every day" is not a reduced restrictive relative clause.
Is "happening in those communities every day" really a reduced restrictive relative clause?

There are shootings happening is just another way of saying shootings are happening, so I'm not sure that it really is a relative clause.

@KateBunting "There are shootings happening" is another way of saying "Shootings are happening". Is "There are shootings happening" also another way of saying "Shootings happen"?

That would be another way of expressing it, yes.

The participial clause happening in those communities every day complements "shootings", expressing what they are "doing"  : they are "happening every day".

There was a coat hanging on a peg in the foyer.
There's a girl scout knocking on the door, selling cookies.
There are twisters moving across the Oklahoma panhandle.

P.S. On the issue of "reduced relative clause", that is a somewhat paleontological approach.  I think it would be better to keep one's attention on the surface characteristics of the clause.   It also gives relativizers a kind of primacy, when the inverse view might be that they're a sort of unnecessary crutch. Indeed, there are dialects of English where this is grammatical:

There's a man has his coat on inside-out wanting to say a few words.


Source: https://www.bleedcubbieblue.com/2019/11/13/20962562/gabe-kapler-questions-giants-new-manager <Example: There are questions surrounding Gabe Kapler that still need to be answered> How about this example? The participal clause "surrounding Gabe Kapler" doesn't express what they are "doing".

@Englishgood I would disagree. The questions are indeed surrounding Gabe Kapler, but in a figurative sense.  Compare "There are questions dogging Gabe Kapler".

<Example: There are questions surrounding Gabe Kapler that still need to be answered> What exactly does "that" refer to? Does it refer to just "questions" or does it refer to "questions surrounding Gabe Kapler"?

@Englishgood If your underlying question is whether I consider surrounding Gabe Kapler supplemental or integral to questions, I would say integral.
